# Обязательно ли использовать классы в C#?

Tags: c#, c

Наверное, глупый вопрос, но можно ли писать код на C# без класса и метода?

Comment: В си - можно точно(зачем поставили тег си?), там какраз с классами туговато :) а вот в шарпе - не факт :) скорее нет чем да, как минимум идеология шарпа была срисована с java и там возможности функционального программирования порезаны :)

Comment: Ну наверное можно, но зачем? )

Comment: @CrazyElf  скорее всего ТС сишник и привык писать так. Вообще довольно странно видеть людей, которые переходят на другой язык и пытаются всячески вставлять писать огромные костылища , чтобы было так, как привыкли в старом языке. Классика.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Класика еще какая, первые пару языков так и учатся кмк :)

Comment: Да использовать C# классы и методы обязательно, даже когда метод статический придется создавать для него бесполезный класс-обетку. Предложения разрешить методы прямо в пространстве имен вылезают регулярно, однако вроде как никаких особых подвижек в этом направлении нет и, наверное, не будет. Ведь в java было сделано точно так же.

Comment: Возможно, автор вопроса просто хочет [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Comment: C# без ООП как безалкогольное пиво - первый шаг к резиновой женщине. А вообще `Console.WriteLine` - это вызов МЕТОДА `WriteLine` у КЛАССА `Console`. Так что черт его знает, что вы на самом деле хотите узнать.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная, кажется, с C# 9 (точно не уверен) - можно.

Например, вполне работоспособный код:

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
int x = 1, y = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) y += x;
Console.WriteLine(x+y);
```

Но, как в том анекдоте:
— Доктор, я буду жить?...
— А смысл?...

Comment: Это называется top-level statements, появились в C# 10.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements

Только на уровне IL это всё равно компилируется в классы. И тот же IL Spy декомпилирует это в виде классов.

Comment: @user11354240 это уже детали реализации. Точно так же можно говорить, что в конечном итоге никаких классов нет, так как машинный код их в принципе не знает...

Comment: Это достаточно существенная деталь реализации - как минимум неявно создаваемый класс является вполне явным и наличествующим для reflection. И из-за этого кто-то будет недоумевать, почему программа из единственной строчки Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine) вдруг выводит какие-то имена классов.

Answer (score -1):

Что значит без метода? У вас в любом случае вызывается какой то метод даже при старте программы или обработчик кнопки. Другой вопрос если вы не понимаете как работать с ООП, в частности с классами. Тогда ответ на ваш вопрос- да. Можно писать код в C# не используя классы и он даже будет работать, но в таком случае вы должны понимать что не используете полностью функционал языка, я бы даже сказал не используете вообще. Также если  вы не будете создавать даже статичных классов, я подозреваю что ваш код будет мягко говоря трудно читаемым и тяжело поддерживаемым. Почитаете хотя бы это [Зачем нужно ООП](https://blog.skillfactory.ru/glossary/oop-obektno-orientirovannoe-programmirovanie/#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%2D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C,%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0.).